# Почему vs code пропускает русские буквы в названии паки?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Кто работает в vs code помогите: у меня имя папки пользователя на русском, и первую букву этого имени vs code почему-то игнорирует (проблема проявилась не сразу), и поэтому путь к какому-то файлу не правильный, из-за этого программа на c++ не запускается. Кто сталкивался, как решить? Я пока единственное решение вижу - изменить имя папки на англ.[image: вот такая ошибка][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема может быть не с вскодом, а с используемым терминалом

Comment: Меняйте имя папки.